# Any way to salvage this Wayfair gazebo roof?

Tags: roof, outdoor, patio, pergola

A few years ago I picked up a [gazebo from Wayfair](https://www.wayfair.com/outdoor/pdp/sol-72-outdoor-acree-12-ft-w-x-10-ft-d-aluminum-patio-gazebo-w003209203.html). Hail has not been kind to the roof. The roof is made from these thick sheets of mostly hollow plastic that's similar in cross-section to cardboard.

Wayfair gave me the number of the supplier, but it's disconnected, so I probably can't replace the roof panels. If I try to fabricate my own roof panels they'll probably be significantly heavier, and probably won't join as neatly as the OEM, leading to leaks. I'm thinking about some sort of fabric cover, but not sure if anyone makes something that will fit. I'd like to salvage what I can of this, the frame is good, bolted down into my concrete, and I've mounted sunshades to the sides.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You haven't been clear on the problem, and we can't see it. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise with enough information so we can help.

Comment: Photos of the damage, and of the supporting structure, would probably help.

Comment: "they'll probably be significantly heavier" - take a piece of the corrugated plastic out, cut it to the appropriate size and weigh it, then look for more plastic of the same weight per sq ft.  "probably won't join as neatly" - buy extra so when you mess up a cut you can do it over, or, measure thrice, cut once. "leading to leaks" - when in doubt caulk it out.

Comment: If you wanted it to last significantly longer (albeit at a high cost), smoked lexan would be, um, bulletproof. Find a local plastics supplier and they’ll cut new to match your old pieces.

Comment: Post a few photos of the panel and damage.  But wood probably be too heavy.

Answer (score 3):

Hollow plastic similar in cross section to cardboard sounds like [Coroplast](https://www.coroplast.com/)™, also known as corrugated plastic. Images from linked site:

[image: Coroplast™ print application]

I've used 4x8 sheets of the stuff as the foundation for hurricane protection on windows. The sign material is usually about a quarter inch thick, but the stuff can be purchased in half-inch (possibly greater) thicknesses. It cuts easily with a sharp knife although an oscillating tool makes much quicker work, with a bit more mess.

Various colors are available, and you may want to check out UV protection as well.

Comment: Generically this is "corrugated plastic".  The thin stuff is used for real estate and political lawn signs.  The heaviest is pretty strong.  Get it from a sign making place.  You could also look at corrugated plastic roofing (wavy sheets of hard plastic) or metal roofing or aluminum siding if you add some support of your own.

Comment: You would need specific considerations to ensure this isn't ruined by hail as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permanent cabana fixture in a place that gets intense hail. Anyone else in this climate would put their sun-equipment away when the weather turns. If you want to keep it out, you need to beef it up significantly. One option is to call it a loss and try an outdoor fixture that can withstand all seasons of climate that you experience. Another option is to think top down, literally. A structure like this could still be built with asphalt shingles tacked into OSB, built on a roof that is spanned correctly for this load. This could be as simple as fitting weather fence posts inside the L-brackets, and then deck joists via hangers.